# Applying multiple classes in CSS [External Stylesheet]

Tags: python, html, css

I am simply trying to apply this type of css class to a p element. And yes I am properly referencing the external stylesheet.

```
.no_curators_followed .no_curators_ctn p {
    color: #c6d4df;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

but, nothing works when I try it...

```
<p class="no_curators_followed no_curators_ctn p">HELLO WORLD</p>
```

Comment: I think the class name to reference in CSS should be: `.no_curators_followed no curators_ctn p`, the way it is currently laid out it is looking for a `p` tag in the class `no_curators_ctn` in the class: `no_curators_followed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `class1 class2 class3 { styles }` you are selecting the `class3` element that is a child of `class2` that is a child of `class1`. You are not selecting the element with all those 3 classes.

To select the element `<p class="class1 class2 class3">` in CSS you should write `.class1.class2.class3` ( no spaces )

```css
.class1.class2.class3 {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<p class="class1 class2 class3">Select me</p>
```

If you want to be more specific and add the tag name of the element ( p, h1, a, li etc. ) to the selector, you should add without dots (`.`) like this `p.class1.class2.class3`

**EDIT**

After your comment i understand that you need to use the style which you cannot edit. So to use that style, the HTML structure should look like :

```css
.no_curators_followed .no_curators_ctn p {
  color: #c6d4df;
  font-size: 17px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="no_curators_followed">
  <div class="no_curators_ctn">
    <p> Change me </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, the p element should be at the beginning if it's to be included like in the question, so `p.class1.class2`

Comment: It is not my css file to edit, I am just referencing it.

Comment: @jimbob542 made an edit to my answer. Please tell me if this is what you wanted.

Comment: @MihaiT Do you also know if there is a way to only apply the inner most child element while ignoring the css of the outer elements. For example, in this case say I only wanted to apply no_curators_ctn but, ignore any css that would come by referencing no_curators_followed ?

Comment: So essentially you want to ' filter ' through the css styles you are importing ? No, that's not possible. You can overwrite the ones you do not need with default values but you cannot select which ones to use. Once you import a css file, you get all the styles. Or maybe i didn't understand the question correctly

Comment: @MihaiT No you understand. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help. CHeers :D

Answer (score 1):

The way you write your CSS right now would be for html written like below :

```
<div class="no_curators_followed">
    <div class="no_curators_ctn">
        <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For html like this

```
<p class="no_curators_followed no_curators_ctn p">HELLO WORLD</p>
```

You can just use

```
.no_curators_followed{
    color: #c6d4df;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the CSS and you just have access to the HTML, then the correct syntax for  this CSS `.no_curators_followed .no_curators_ctn p` is:

```html
<div class="no_curators_followed">
    <div class="no_curators_ctn">
        <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because `.no_curators_followed .no_curators_ctn p` means that the parent is an element with the class `no_curators_followed`, which has a child of class `no_curators_ctn`, which has an element of `p`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this in your stylesheet

remove your space between tow class and add **.(dot)** before **p** class

```
.no_curators_followed.no_curators_ctn.p {
    color: #c6d4df;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```